# Is Gift of Alacrity legal in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, dnd-adventurers-league

I'm creating a character for D&D Adventurers League and wanted to make a warlock with the Fey Touched feat, which states:

> You learn the Misty Step spell and one 1st-level spell of your choice. The 1st-level spell must be from the Divination or Enchantment school of magic. You can cast each of these spells without expending a spell slot. Once you cast either of these spells in this way, you can’t cast that spell in this way again until you finish a long rest. You can also cast these spells using spell slots you have of the appropriate level. The spells’ spellcasting ability is the ability increased by this feat.

Gift of Alacrity is a 1st-level divination spell introduced in Explorer's Guide to Wildemount that is exclusive to the spell list of the Chronurgy wizard subclass, meaning that most AL-legal characters cannot use it due to the subclass's lack of legality. However, Fey Touched is AL-legal. In addition, Fey Touched only places restrictions on the 1st-level spell's school of magic, not on spell list, and the most recent AL player's guide (https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/DDAL_PlayersGuidev11_0.pdf) does not place restrictions on spells learned by character advancement, nor does it contain the PHB+1 rule previously used by Adventurers League games. Is Gift of Alacrity therefore now legally attainable in Adventurers League?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### No, *gift of alacrity* is not AL legal.

The first page of the DDAL Player's Guide has a list of books from which you may select various features, the sidebar "**WHAT RULEBOOKS SHOULD I USE?**", and *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount* is not on that list:

> ##### WHAT RULEBOOKS SHOULD I USE?
>
> You can use non-optional rules found in the Player’s Handbook,
> the Basic Rules, and all the books listed below. If a rule has been
> reprinted in a newer resource, you must always use the latest
> printing.
>
> - *Fizban’s Treasury of Dragons* (FTD) (on October 19, 2021)
> - *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* (MTF)
> - *Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide* (SCAG)
> - *Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything* (TCE)
> - *Volo’s Guide to Monsters* (VGM)
> - *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* (XGE)
> - Races or backgrounds published in select adventure product
>   (see the FAQ)
> - Backgrounds from premier organizer products (see the FAQ)
>
> You may also use the rules found in the following digital
> publications:
>
> - *Elemental Evil Player’s Companion* (EEPC)
> - *Locathah Rising* (LR)
> - *The Tortle Package* (TP)
>
> Additionally, the following variant or optional rules are available:
>
> - Blessed of Corellon (MTF)
> - Chapter 6: Customization Options (PH)
> - Customizing Your Origin (TCE)
> - Half-Elf and Tiefling Variants (SCAG/MTF)
> - Option: Human Languages (SCAG)
> - Optional Class Features (TCE)
> - Variant Human Traits (PH)

When selecting spells for an Adventurer’s League caster character, your complete spell list is actually the union of several different lists: the base spell list for your class from the *Player’s Handbook*, the expanded spell list for your class printed in *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* (lists start on pg. 147), the expanded spell lists offered as optional class features in *Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything*, and the draconic magic spells printed in *Fizban’s Treasury of Dragons*. I’m pretty sure all the spells that were first printed in *Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide* and the *Elemental Evil Player’s Companion* were reprinted in *Tasha’s Cauldron*, though if I am mistaken the options printed there are available as well (as noted in the quote, you must use the most recent printing of a spell in AL).

Comment: You may want to link to and/or include the version number of the AL Player's Guide you're referencing, as AL rules seem to change somewhat often from season to season.