# Is Dunamancy legal in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, dnd-adventurers-league

Is Dunamancy legal in Adventurers League?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Gift of Alacrity legal in Adventurers League?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/199027/is-gift-of-alacrity-legal-in-adventurers-league)

Comment: Is your question about the spells, or the wizard subclasses, or both?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov No. Just because two questions might have the same answer does not make them duplicates. They are distinct questions; the word “dunamancy” appears nowhere in either question or answers to that question. And even knowing that answer doesn’t necessarily answer this one. For instance, while both appear in _Explorer’s Guide to Wildemount_, and that question covers that source in AL play, it is possible that dunamancy is—or will be—published in another sourcebook that would be allowed in the AL. (Unlikely, but still.)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Better almost-duplicate (in that it's more general to all *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount" content in relation to AL play): [How "official" is the Explorer's Guide to Wildemount book?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170699/28941) (the title doesn't mention AL, but it explicitly asks in the body "Is it an AL-legal sourcebook?")

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh, I answered that one too.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov With the amount of answers you have contributed to this site (over 1,400!) I think it is entirely forgiveable that you did not remember you had already done this before.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin except this time it was twice before.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Im afraid \$1400!\$ is about \$3.46\times 10^{3798}\$.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That will be tough to reach indeed, as it exceeds the number of atoms in the universe by a wide margin. So I think we need to assume the orignal intent of the symbol was to express an exclamation, as part of the rest of the text.

Answer (score 13):

#### No.

The [Adventurer’s League Player’s Guide v12.1](https://media.wizards.com/2022/dnd/downloads/DDAL_PlayersGuidev12_1.pdf) lists the eligible sourcebooks for use in AL play:

> ##### WHAT RULEBOOKS SHOULD I USE?
>
> You can use non-optional rules found in the Player’s Handbook,
> the Basic Rules, and all the books listed below. If a rule has been
> reprinted in a newer resource, you must always use the latest
> printing.
>
> - *Fizban’s Treasury of Dragons* (FTD)
> - *Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse* (MPMM)
> - *Spelljammer: Adventures in Space* (SAS) (on August 16, 2022)*
> - *Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide* (SCAG)
> - *Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything* (TCE)
> - *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* (XGE)
> - Additional options as presented in the FAQ
>
> You may also use the rules found in the following digital
> publications:
>
> - *Elemental Evil Player’s Companion* (EEPC)
> - *Locathah Rising* (LR)
>
> Additionally, the following variant or optional rules are available:
>
> - Chapter 6: Customization Options (PH)
> - Customizing Your Origin (TCE)
> - Half-Elf and Tiefling Variants (SCAG)
> - Option: Human Languages (SCAG)
> - Optional Class Features (TCE)
> - Variant Human Traits (PH)
>
> *Races from the Unearthed Arcana playtest “Travelers of the Multiverse” are available for play in *Spelljammer Academy* adventures prior to August 16, which must then be updated to the rules present in *Spelljammer: Adventures in Space* when playing on or after August 16.

*Explorer’s Guide to Wildemount*, the sourcebook for dunamancy spells and subclasses, is not on this list.